# ValueError: math domain error in StatsForecast?

Tags: python, time-series

My data contains value like this, can be called df_de

| ds | unique_id | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | 6e1b44c1-17be-48f8-9e64-0333d90d3f8c | 100 |
| 2023-02-05 | 0530b9a4-857f-4f2e-9c7a-1864bbd5dca3 | 4000 |
| 2023-02-05 | 7f1ef93f-25f5-45fd-9a96-cc82674ea779 | 250 |
| 2023-02-05 | 89167eca-4dce-4ef0-9ab4-53be779ff264 | 100 |
| 2023-02-05 | 459da75b-7eac-4d43-850a-7aba065a6220 | 520 |

**ds** is the weekend date, so that data is as on end of the week. unique_id is the usercode and y is the value of sales done by user. There are total 16 weeks for each user.

i'm trying to forecast the sales by each user. below is the code.

I have splitted into train and validation.

```
train = df_de.loc[df_de['ds'] <= '2023-02-26']
valid = df_de.loc[(df_de['ds'] > '2023-02-26')]
h = valid['ds'].nunique()

model = StatsForecast(models=[AutoARIMA(season_length=7)], freq='W', n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(train)
```

Here I'm getting the error of ValueError: math domain error in model.fit(train), please help me out. below is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/jupyter-gopi_shankar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsforecast/core.py", line 73, in fit
    fm[i, i_model] = new_model.fit(y=y, X=X)
  File "/home/jupyter-gopi_shankar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsforecast/models.py", line 246, in fit
    self.model_ = auto_arima_f(
  File "/home/jupyter-gopi_shankar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsforecast/arima.py", line 1843, in auto_arima_f
    fit = Arima(x, order=(0, 0, 0), include_mean=False)
  File "/home/jupyter-gopi_shankar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsforecast/arima.py", line 1492, in Arima
    tmp["bic"] = tmp["aic"] + npar * (math.log(nstar) - 2)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Solved! Please ignore.

Comment: How was it solved ^^

Comment: How was it solved?

Comment: @GopiS How did you solve it?

Comment: Found the following discussion to be useful - https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/discussions/654

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to take the log of a negative number. That would cause the domain error:

```
>>> math.log(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```